# How to manage fine grain permissions in Elasticsearch?

Tags: permissions, elasticsearch

I need to store in a consistent way the role/groups that can access the information but I'm not sure what's the best way to do it.

Summary: I have 2 kinds of docs "tweet" and "blog":

- At `tweet` level, I store the group name allowed to access the information
- `blog` is more complex, there are metadata (`title`, `description`, `nature`, ...) but some of those informations can be restricted to some groups of user (only `admin`, or `logged_in` users)

**What the best way to map this with Elasticsearch ?**

As of today, I end up with documents like:

```
/tweet/455
{
    id: 112,
    ugroups: [ "restricted_user", "admin" ],
    description: "foo",
},
{
    id: 113,
    ugroups: [ "anonymous" ]
    description: "foo",
}
```

and

```
/blog/500
{
    id: 5,
    fields: [
        {
            "nature": {
                "value": "foo",
                "ugroup": [ "admin" ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
{
    id: 6,
    fields: [
        {
            "comment": {
                "value": "foo",
                "ugroup": [ "anonymous" ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

When user want to search in `tweet`, that's easy, I build a `term` query with words submitted by the user and I append the groups the user belongs to this query.

But how to make a query that will take this "ugroup" thing at various level ?

Ideally I could issue a query like:

- search in `tweet` with `tweet.ugroup: "anonymous"` and in `blog` with `blog.fields.*.ugroup: "anonymous"`

**Is there a way to write such a query ?**